# In the below java program I didn't understand flow of execution and about "this" keyword execution?

Tags: java

```
class This
{
    This()
    {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    public static void main(String [] raja)
    {
        new This();
        System.out.println(new This());
    }
}


output:
This@470285d8
This@76a14c53
This@76a14c53
```

why the output of the program is printed 3 times?And this keyword refers to current class instance but here why the references are different i.e., the first reference is different from the other two references why?

same code with small change by creating reference t:

```
class This
{
    This()
    {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    public static void main(String [] raja)
    {
        This t = new This();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}

output:
This@76a14c53
This@76a14c53
```

This is printing only two lines but why the above program is printing 3 times,and why here the references are not changing.

Comment: Don't name your class `This`. It's confusing.

Comment: I have asked why it is printing 3 times in the 1st program and why there is a variation in the references @Jens

Comment: Try with an empty `main` block and see how you go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor prints one line, so :

```
new This();
System.out.println(new This());
```

Here you call the constructor twice, and `System.out.println()` also prints a line, so you get three lines.
Also, you are creating **two** distinct `This` objects.

In your second example, the constructor is only called once, so you get only two lines.
This example creates only **one** `This` object :

```
This t = new This();
System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: can you explain me here why there is difference in the references because this is a current class object but why there is a variation in references.

Comment: In your first example you actually create two distinct objects, and pass the second one to System.out.println(). In the second example, you create only one object.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case you have created 2 objects ,since the constructor  and  main has `System.out.println(this)` . program prints 3 times.

in the second case you've created only one object so `System.out.println(this)` in constructor and main run and prints object `toString()` result 2 times

Answer (score 0):

```
class This
{
    This() // This is the constructor. It gets called automatically everytime a new instance is created
    {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
public static void main(String [] raja)
{
    new This(); // Second instance
    System.out.println(new This()); // Third instance
}
```

And First instance is made when you first run the program. Hence you get 3 outputs.

In your second code, you create an object of `This` and just call that. So total two instances: First the one when you run. Second, the one you created as: `This t = new This();`. Hence two outputs in this case.